# How Does Sci-Kit Learn Train Regression Neural Networks (MLPRegressor) So Fast?

Tags: neural-network, scikit-learn, mlp

Why does using the scikit-learn library's MLPRegressor result in such a boost in training time when compared to constructing the network from scratch? I tried both methods and I found that writing the code from scratch yielded an average training time of ~10 seconds while Sci-Kit Learn trained almost instantly?

Comment: My suspicion would be that Scikit-Learn utilises a lot of `numpy`, which in turn utilises `C` (I could be wrong about that!) - a high-performant low-level language.

Comment: If I was to code an ANN from scratch in C then do you think it would perform about the same as Scikit-learn (Not that I'll actually do that!)

Comment: If you are intelligent enough and know how to optimize your code like hell, then Yes, Just check their Source code simple to see :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scikit-learn use numpy and cython to speed-up code.